# What is the origin of the error message 'Signup not authorized, is limited to a specific company'

Tags: onelogin

We are getting the error message 'Signup not authorized, is limited to a specific company' when we get a idp login into our OneLogin open source Java toolkit. We can not find anything about this message, where does it come from?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this question or answer would be of any value to future users of this site, as it is the result of your own mistake in your own source. Both the question and answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK we found where the message comes from, from our own application. It was hard to find since it was hidden in the text resources/properties files.